# Kakfa local shell window closing time

Tags: powershell, shell, apache-kafka

I am new to kafka and following this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_basic_operations.htm

I have installed and configure everything zookeeper, kafka etc and it's working fine. But when I run any command my output terminal window close within second, so I am not able to see output. Is there property to set output window time?

```
kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

I used this command to list topic but listed topics window closed not given enough time me to see.

Comment: You are aware that the tutorial you linked is for Unix 'shells', aren't you? It is not common for people to try to invoke Unix Shell scripts in Windows [[tag:cmd]]. Please revisit your question and [edit] it to clarify your used tags and properly explain your exhibited issue.

Comment: I also tried it with shell terminal but had same issue. I am editing my tags as well.

Comment: Powershell doesn't run `.sh` scripts

Answer (score 1):

Powershell doesn't run `.sh` scripts. If CMD or Powershell are closing its because you're getting a fatal exception and should really be using `bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat`, which ran on its own with no arguments should print help text, and not close any window

Also relevant - [Run Kafka on WSL2](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/) instead of direct in windows if you want to avoid LogCleaner errors you'll eventually find with file permissions

I also suggest following the official Kafka website documentation since the Zookeeper flag is deprecated